# resp = conn.urlopen( sock.connect((remote_host, remote_port))r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)raise err

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

Estoy intentando conseguir un token de autorizacion de la pagina de forntite a través de la librería requests de python. Tengo un problema al hacer una request de tipo post hacia la pagina que me da el token. Este es mi codigo:

```
def check_mail(email, password, proxylist, proxy_type):
    #Importo proxys, cuentas, y datos para el programa
    global checked, bad, good, cpm1, cpm2, banned, errors
    sess = requests.Session()
    if proxy_type == 1:
        proxy_to_use = random.choice(proxylist)
        try: 
            proxy = random.choice(proxylist)
            proxy_form = {'http': f"http://{proxy}", 'https': f"https://{proxy}"}
        except Exception:
            pass

    elif proxy_type == 2:
        proxy = random.choice(proxylist)
        line = f"socks4://{proxy}"
        proxy_form = {'http': line, 'https': line}
    elif proxy_type == 3:
        try: 
            proxy = random.choice(proxylist)
            line = f"socks5://{proxy}"
            proxy_form = {'http': line, 'https': line}
        except Exception:
                pass
    else:
        pass
    #Defino las URL a las que voy a hacerles GET & POST, junto a un token de autorizacion previamente generado
    excode = "Bearer 9586b26f33a844fe8f4e412dae3f6690"
    url1 = "https://account-public-service-prod.ol.epicgames.com/account/api/oauth/exchange" 
    url2 = "https://account-public-service-prod.ol.epicgames.com/account/api/oauth/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization":excode
    }
    #Primer get, para obtener las cookies
    f = sess.get(url1, headers=headers)
    open('results/FortniteStats/{}/good.txt'.format(current_date), 'a+').write("{}:{}\n".format(f.content, password))
    if not b"errors.com.epicgames.common.oauth.invalid_token" in f.content:
        tk = f.json().get('code')
        print(tk)
        headers2 = {
            "Content-Type:": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "basic MzQ0NmNkNzI2OTRjNGE0NDg1ZDgxYjc3YWRiYjIxNDE6OTIwOWQ0YTVlMjVhNDU3ZmI5YjA3NDg5ZDMxM2I0MWE="
        }
        content={
        "grant_type":"exchange_code",
        "exchange_code":tk
        }
        #Esta es la linea de codigo que me da error :(
        g = sess.post("https://account-public-service-prod.ol.epicgames.com/account/api/oauth/token", proxies=proxy_form, headers=headers2, data=content)
        if not b"errors.com.epicgames.account.oauth.too_many_sessions" in g.content:
            print("2 good")
            tk2 = sess.content["access_token"]
            good+=1
            checked+=1
            cpm1+=1
            open('results/FortniteStats/{}/good.txt'.format(current_date), 'a+').write("{}:{}\n".format(email, password))
        else:
            print("many sessions")
    else:
        print("invalid token")
        errors+=1
```

Y esta es la respuesta que me da de error al hacer el post hacia url2 (https://account-public-service-prod.ol.epicgames.com/account/api/oauth/token)
relleno: 123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123

```
File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 199, in create_connection
          File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 800, in connect resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)          File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 209, in create_connection r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


conn = socks.create_connection(    raise err

  File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 199, in create_connection   File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 199, in create_connection   File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
      File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen   File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request NewConnectionError    conn = socks.create_connection(

f = sess.post("https://account-public-service-prod.ol.epicgames.com/account/api/oauth/token", proxies=proxy_form, headers=headers2, json=content, timeout=200)resp = conn.urlopen(    sock.connect((remote_host, remote_port))r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)raise err
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta :]